# creating svg media controls buttons

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am new to js. Is there a way that i could create play pause and resume button using svg? i tried to create them using svg polygon. but figuring out the co ordinates seem to be a pain.

```
var poly= svg.append("polygon")
    .attr("points" ,"20 3, 60,50 60, 40")
    .attr("fill", "brown");

poly.on('click', poly_click)

function poly_click() {
    console.log("hello");
}
```

i am intending to have separate function handlers for play, pause and stop buttons. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can create play, pause and stop buttons:

```js
var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var play = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "svg");
play.setAttribute("width", "20");
play.setAttribute("height", "20");
var pause = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "svg");
pause.setAttribute("width", "15");
pause.setAttribute("height", "20");
var stop = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "svg");
stop.setAttribute("width", "20");
stop.setAttribute("height", "20");

function playButton() {
    var polygon = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "polygon");
    polygon.setAttribute("points", "0,0 0,20 20,10");
    polygon.setAttribute("fill", "green");
    play.appendChild(polygon);
    document.body.appendChild(play);
}
playButton();

function pauseButton() {
    var path = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "path");
    path.setAttribute("d", "M0,0 L0,20 L5,20 L5,0 L0,0 M10,0 L10,20 L15,20 L15,0, L10,0");
    path.setAttribute("fill", "green");
    pause.appendChild(path);
    document.body.appendChild(pause);
}
pauseButton();

function stopButton() {
    var rect = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "rect");
    rect.setAttribute("width", "20");
    rect.setAttribute("height", "20");
    rect.setAttribute("fill", "red");
    stop.appendChild(rect);
    document.body.appendChild(stop);
}
stopButton();
```

```css
svg {
    margin: 3px;
}
```

Comment: @chipChololate.py I beleive that the 3rd code snippet has to be added to the html? Can we do the same without modifying the html?